# How to add multiple annotations in mkmapview in iphone application?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, latitude-longitude, mkannotation, mkannotationview

In my iphone application , i am getting some custom images, unique id ,latitude and longitude from the database.By using that details i want to add annotations in those latitudes and longitudes with the custom image,and unique id.when i click the annotations the unique id will be passed to the web service.

please refer me some solution or tutorial?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: try to accept some answers for your questions

Answer (score 4):

See this tutorial on MKAnnotations

http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/08/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit-part-3/

or dowload and see how this project works.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html